# Check whether a polynomial ideal is prime in the power series ring

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, commutative-algebra

I would like to know whether the ideal $I = \langle y^{2}(y^{2}-x^{2}) + w^{7}, y^{2}(y^{4}-x^{4}) + z^{7}\rangle$ is prime in $\mathbb{C}[[x,y,z,w]]$, the ring of formal power series in the indeterminates $x,y,z,w$.
It seems that the generators don't factor in the power series ring. But I don't know to how show that the ideal itself is prime.
Thanks for all hints & answers.

Comment: I am not sure if this a useful comment, but you might try to look for another ideal $\mathcal{J} = \mathcal{I}$ with a simpler generators.

Comment: These questions are the best, as Macaulay2 can't help - for now only, apparently - on power series. I will give it a thought.

Comment: @SomeOne Do you have any nice examples where this simplifies such a question?